# jQuery UI tabs not showing up in TestNG report

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, report, testng

I am trying to add a jQuery UI tabs effect to my TestNG reports. When I add it using reporter.log, the jQuery UI tabs shows up in the index.html report, which shows all of the tests inside the test suite. 
[image]
You can see that it works in the image above. I use reporter.log("jquery scripts and code here") to do this. It adds this table for every test step. I can click on the links and it will displays the correct tabs.

But when I open the test report of a specific test inside the test-output folder, the jQuery UI effect does not work anymore.

[image]

^This folder contains two html reports, because I have two tests in my test suite.

[image]
^ This is the report page of ONE of the tests.

[image]

^ This happens when I click on show output

You can see that it is actually displaying everything, but the jQuery UI effect is just not working anymore. Why is this? This is the code I use to add jQuery UI effect.

```
//Report.log adds jqueryui script +css, and adds a fancy way to show test results with tabs
        Reporter.log("<script src=\"http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js\"></script>");
        Reporter.log("<link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css\">");
        Reporter.log("<script> $(function() { $( \".tabs\" ).tabs(); }); </script>");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, it seems that I forgot to add jQuery library itself. Case closed!